# How do I get the id from an input object that's held in an array?

Tags: javascript

Trying to get the id from a collection of inputs held in an array but having difficulty.
HTML

```
<div id="searchData">
<input type="text" id="1" />
<input type="text" id="2" />
<input type="text" id="3" />
</div>
```

---

```
//jS

var searchRes = document.getElementById("searchData").getElementsByTagName("input");

for(x in searchRes){
  alert(x.getAttribute('id'));
}
```

Any help would be ore than appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Use a `for` loop to iterate over array-like objects. `x` is not what you think it is. Have a look at the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: JavaScript's `in` keyword always uses keys/properties rather than values.

Comment: Didn't know that Felix, thanks. Just goes to show how easy it is to misinterpret functions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is wrong.

`for (x in searchRes)` will give you the following values for `x`: `0,1,2`

you should change it to

```
for(x in searchRes){
  alert(searchRes[x].id);
}
```

Comment: Using `for` loops for array-like objects is even better.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could change to this to achieve that. Your for loop is accessing the keys on that Array object right now. This would be easier using the Array prototype function [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var searchRes = document.getElementById("searchData").getElementsByTagName("input");

searchResults.map(function(inputElem) {
  return inputElem.id;
});
```

**EDIT:**
 Jonathan caught me. An HTMLCollection is not an Array. Therefore you can't call Array functions on it until you convert it.

```
var searchRes = document.getElementById("searchData").getElementsByTagName("input");
var searchInputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(searchRes);
searchInputs.map(function(inputElem) {
  return inputElem.id;
});
```

Comment: Note: [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) doesn't return an actual `Array` and [HTMLCollections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) won't have many of the same methods.

Answer (score 0):

`for..in` in javascript does not iterate through the items. It iterates through the property key. This is valid not only for arrays, but any object.

You can use the key to access the actual value:

```
var searchRes = document.getElementById("searchData").getElementsByTagName("input");

for(var key in searchRes){
  alert(searchRes[key].getAttribute('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
for (var i=0; i < searchRes.length; i++){
    alert(searchRes.item(i).getAttribute('id'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied. Just love the way people are always willing to provide advice and guidance. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

When I try a new example like the one below, I get additional undefined outputs. Any idea why? I only have three inputs, why am I getting more than three alerts?

> Thanks

Sorted it using a for loop not a for in. Hope it helps someone.

```
 <div id="all">
First name: <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname"><br>
Age: <input id="age" type="text" name="lname"><br>
</div>



<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById('all').getElementsByTagName("input");
   for(prop in x){ 
  alert(x[prop].id);
}
}
</script>
```